# writing multiple files with writeLines in R

Tags: r, apply, lapply, file-writing

I have a list `cleanFiles` of files where every file in the list consists of multiple lines. There is also a vector called `functionList` that has multiple paths saved to the files of `cleanFiles` so that every clean File has one path where it should be saved.

Now I try to save the lines of the `cleanFiles` list in multiple seperate files. I already tried:

```
lapply(cleanFiles, writeLines, con = file.path(dummyRPath, basename(functionList)))
```

but it results in an error:

> Error in file(con, "w"): invalid 'description' argument

The files are of type .R. How is it possible to write out multiple files to the paths given in `functionList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it would be better to use `mapply`/`Map` :

```
Map(function(x, y) writeLines(x, con = file.path(dummyRPath, basename(y))), 
                   cleanFiles, functionList)
```

In `lapply` you can iterate over the index of the file to access both  `cleanFiles` and `functionList`.

```
lapply(seq_along(cleanFiles), function(i) 
       writeLines(cleanFiles[[i]],  
       con = file.path(dummyRPath, basename(functionList[i]))))
```